# In Nextjs. How do i separate or determine what should be an app or just a regular rendering page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, next.js

I'm in the very beginning of learning nextjs after doing a bit of react. And my question is about rendering and routing and how to separate app page and regular page. I don't fully understand this concept yet, and having some trouble fining information. 
First of all,  We do not always want the whole webpage to load as a single web app. There could be many reasons for that.

Maybe I want the:

```
home  
/about
/contact
```

page to load when the client actually clicks on it.
Then I would have another page with some kind of calculation function, components and a lot of things happens along that, on for instance
 `/myapp`. 
This page will be rendered as a web app separated from about, and contact page. And what if I want to have several apps on my webpage, maybe `/myapp2`. How's the best practice to separate those two apps to be rendered simultaneously and only when the client is on the apps url. I maybe want to separate those to app because they don't have anything in common or sharing any common components.

So to sum it up, how do I separate what part of my webpage that should be rendered as a regular page, and what part should be rendered as a web app.

Hope for some clarifying answer
Thanks and cheers!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow, is your question regarding single page apps versus multi page apps? And how to mix both in Next.js?

Comment: Do I need to choose between those or can it be mixed?

Comment: In Next.js you can consider each pages as an app on it's own. Yet, Next.js also "connects" your pages with components like Link, so it behaves as a normal Single Page Application. To simplify, I would tend to consider a Next.js as a normal single page application (like create-react-app or whatever), with some smart code-splitting. This is very simplified, because Next.js is quite complex under the hood.